# Running Multiple perl script simultaneously

Tags: perl

I have three identical perl script; say test1.pl, test2.pl, test3.pl

Each perl script have a set of commands. For example;

command to run test1.pl **`perl test1.pl arg1 arg2 &`;**

test1.pl

```
#!usr/bin/perl

`command1`;   ### Takes ~30 Minute and use 30 core
`command2`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 2 core
`command3`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 1 core
`command4`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 1 core
```

And similar for test2.pl and test3.pl

Now, I want to utilize the idle cpu threads by running the test2.pl as soon as the command1 in test1.pl finishes.
So that **command1 in the test2.pl** can use idle threads **while** the **"command2, command3 and command4 can be finished simultaneously** too.

And same in the next step (Run test3.pl as soon as command 1 in test2.pl finishes).

**Therefore; test1.pl might looks like this;**

test1.pl

```
#!usr/bin/perl

`command1`;   ### Takes ~30 Minute and use 30 core

**`perl test2.pl arg3 arg4 &`;**

`command2`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 2 core

`command3`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 1 core

`command4`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 1 core
```

However, running (test2.pl) like this will pause the test1.pl remaining commands. So not a good way.

Any commend or suggestions.
Thanks.

Amit

Answer (score 1):

Your perl script may start background processes (X &) itself.  It may use fork function call.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

`command1`;   ### Takes ~30 Minute and use 30 core

# start child process
my $child_pid = fork() // die "Can't fork: $!"; # die unless defined($child_pid);
if ($child_pid == 0 ) {
   # am the child process
   exec( 'perl', 'test2.pl' );
   die "exec failed!";
}
# am the parent process

`command2`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 2 core
`command3`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 1 core
`command4`;   ### Takes ~10 Minute and use 1 core

 # wait for the child process to finish 
 waitpid $child_pid, 0;
```

Comment: I just used  `xterm -hold -e 'perl test2.pl'`; instead of the exec( 'perl', 'test2.pl' );, since anyhow my child process was not starting while using the exec() function.

Comment: Make sure to put `exit;` at the end of `if` block. Otherwise your child process will execute parent process code **too**.

Comment: Yes I am.But looks like my reputation point is too low for this. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Method: 1

By using Parallel:: ForkManager, you are able to run the script in parallel.

```
# you create list and feed into for loop
for loop[i]:
   execute the perl script[i]
end
```

Method: 2

We have the option to execute multiple Perl scripts in a single line by using `&` in Linux terminal.

Example: `perl script1 & perl script2 & perl script3`

Script 1, 2, 3 will be run inparallel.